# Lan is Working . But Wifi isn't connecting

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet-connection

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I am connecting Lan cable, internet is working fine, but when I disconnect Lan and switch on wifi ,Internet isn't working. Is there any additional drivers to be installed ??

Answer (score 0):

It may be requirement of any  propriety driver.You can check it with searching `additional` `drivers` in dash. Open it It will automatically search for propriety drivers for your wifi and click on install button.

Comment: When I opened _additional drivers_ it is showing an error message **Downloading package indexes failed,please check your network status.Most drivers will not be available.**

Comment: make sure that internet is on (inserted LAN cable).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure if your wireless card is detected using "ifconfig | grep wlan*" command.
If it is detected then configured your wlan setting as "manual" or "dhcp". Make sure you are able to ping to your modem when using this wlan.

Comment: how to check that command ?